# Can you have one view be a subview for several different views for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiview, subview

Is it possible to add the same view instance as a subview of two different views at the same time?  I'm trying to do this but it only shows up on the last one it was added as a subview to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, a view can only be in a single view hierarchy at a time. If you add it to another view, it will automatically be removed from its previous view. Also, if you add it to the *same* view that it was already in, it will automatically be removed and re-added as the top-most item (however, this is much less efficient than just simply changing its position directly).

Comment: okay, so i thought that, so i tried making a copy of the view by doing `UIImageView *imgCopy = [imgView copy];` but that didn't work either, the same thing happened.  thoughts?

Comment: @marty: You can't copy views. You have to create two separate image views and assign the image to each of them.

Comment: well that's very misleading since there's a `copy` method.

Comment: @marty: Actually, UIView don't implement NSCopying. There shouldn't be any copy method available. It should just crash, but even if it does ignore a copy message, the docs don't declare it, so it doesn't support it.

Comment: I'm glad I read this. I'm working on an app where I need to move subviews from one view to another. Now i know it's easier than I thought. I can simply add them to the new view.