# Adding SwiftUI View to UIKit two UIViews VIA addSubView. One is adding but second is not

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, addsubview

I am adding SwiftUI View 'TestView' to contentView1 and contentView2. But it is adding to contentView2 only.
anyone please help me understand that why SwiftUI View isn't adding to contentView1. I have ensured that outlets are connected properly.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet var contentView1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var contentView2: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: TestView())
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChild(vc)
        contentView1.addSubview(vc.view)
        contentView2.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SwiftUI")
            .onAppear(perform: {
                print("OnAppear Called")
            })
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [A `UIView` can only have one parent at a time.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4745759/5133585) You cannot add the same view to both `contentView1` and `contentView2`. How about making another `UIHostingController`? Also your constraints doesn't quite make sense...

Comment: What part of "a UIView can only have one parent at a time" do you not understand? Did you see the linked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         contentView1.addSubview(vc.view)
>         contentView2.addSubview(vc.view)
> ```

A given view can only have one parent view — you can't add the same view to two different views and expect it to show up twice. Create two separate views and add them to each of your content views, and you'll see them both.